# URL-rewriting isn't working in another htdocs folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

First of all, I simply wanted to use another folder as the default `htdocs` directory.
In order to do so, I added these lines into my `httpd.conf`:

```
AliasMatch ^/php/(.+)$ F:/PHP/$1
<Directory "F:/PHP/*">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The problem I experienced was that the URL rewriting I had set up for the former `htdocs` wasn't working properly. To do the rewriting, I had used this `RewriteRule` directive in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^((?:(user|admin|debug)/)?[a-z_/]+)/(?:([0-9]+)/)?$ index.php?page=$1&auth=$2&id=$3
```

... which was located in "F:/PHP/lif-web-interface/" on my drive.

The URL I want to display is the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1/php/lif-web-interface/factionlist/
```

If it had performed correctly, I would have seen a rewritten URL with collected GET parameters on its end. When I had tried to add the `[R]` parameter, the output I got changed into the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1/F:/PHP/lif-web-interface/index.php?page=factionlist&auth=&id=
```

... which, surprisingly, was the thing I wanted to see. But yet, I didn't want to redirect onto that page, I just wanted to replace the URL.

Do you have suggestions what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've put those rules in the htaccess file in the `F:/PHP` folder. If so, then try adding a base:

```
RewriteBase /php/
RewriteRule ^((?:(user|admin|debug)/)?[a-z_/]+)/(?:([0-9]+)/)?$ index.php?page=$1&auth=$2&id=$3
```

If the rules are in the document root, then you need to include the path:

```
RewriteRule ^php/((?:(user|admin|debug)/)?[a-z_/]+)/(?:([0-9]+)/)?$ /php/index.php?page=$1&auth=$2&id=$3
```

Comment: .htaccess is located in "F:/PHP/lif-web-interface/" (there is the index.php, too)

Comment: I've just tried to add a `RewriteBase /php/lif-web-interface/` and it's working, thanks! But is there any universal solution (for httpd.conf)?